# Could wind be causing my high efficiency furnace exhaust to back up into the house?

Tags: furnace

I am Toronto based, and just installed a new high efficiency furnace (York YP9C 080 model) in November. Later on I smell odor in my house when the heat started. It is more apparent when it is a gusty windy night. I have called Enbridge to come and investigate if there is gas leaking from the pipe. But it isn't. the odor makes my eye dry and my throat feels bitter sometimes. I have checked my vent termination outside of my house; tried to do some diagnostic myself with advice from some friends.

I realize my back yard environmental conditions have been changed since the snow storm last year. My two neighbors have cut their trees down after the ice storm last year. My house is situated at the end of a crescent. The back yard looks as if it is the end of a tunnel. I am not sure if the vent termination is affected by wind gust factor. If is the case, a technician recommended me to move the vent to the other direction inside the house. It can be costly. Will you recommend I use a tee vent so the wind cannot directly impact the force back to the exhaust pipe. I had two nights ago when the wind was really strong, in the middle of the night, I even smell gas but it went away a few minutes later. I am not sure if the strong wind create the force that pressure the exhaust back to the furnace and caused this gas smell.

Please advise if a tee can put on the exhaust pipe can help? or other recommendations can be made?

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation; however, my vent termination is installed outside the wall of the house. It is not through the chimney. The two pipes (Exhaust and air intake) are installed vertically with over 1 ft apart from the two entries. My question is if i can use a "tee" at the end of the exhaust pipe to minimize the impact of direct wind pressure going back to the pipe during strong gusty wind nights. I am not sure if that will work. I believe our chimney has already been closed. Are we still able to use the neutral pipe cap you recommend?

Comment: Recommendation: install a CO detector.

Answer (score 2):

I found a wind neutral pipe cap (right in photo) and installed it six years ago, and at least five major PNW storms ago.  It has performed flawlessly and required no maintenance.

It has a geometric baffle design which neutralizes excess air infiltration/exfiltration by balancing air flow somehow, regardless of direction.  I think it is [this one](http://www.ventingpipe.com/DuraVent-3GVVTH-Aluminum-High-Wind-Cap-with-3-Inch-Inner-Diameter/p1761337?source=gg-gba-pla_with_promotion_1761337____32091895622&s_kwcid=PTC!pla!!!77488253222!g!!32091895622&gclid=CImV_YfP5MICFZCVfgod-n4A9A).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've always seen a t or similar baffle on the exhaust.  Shouldn't hurt, might be all you need.  On mine the t runs vertically;  I think that's standard practice.